# PHP - How do I access specific array values in nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested

I have an array like this:

```
    Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 510 
        [1] => 984 
        [2] => 1045 
        [3] => 2068 
        [4] => 1054 
        [5] => 673 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1163 
        [1] => 1982 
        [2] => 2067 
        [3] => 3989 
        [4] => 1940 
        [5] => 1242 
        ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => june 
        [1] => july 
        [2] => august 
        [3] => september 
        [4] => october 
        [5] => november 
        ) 
    )
```

I want to access only one of the arrays within the array at a time and echo them out.

For example, I would get: 510, 984, 1045, 2068, 1054, and 673 as one result.

I've looked at multiple threads and answers but nothing that quite solves my issue, I've been able to print out all the values but I just want some specifically.

I'd store it in the variable: `$array_item`

My most recent attempt was:

```
foreach ($array_item as $inner) {
if (is_array($inner)) {
    foreach ($inner[0] as $value) {
        echo "$value \n";
    }
}
}
```

Which gives me: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

I thought for sure that would work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I want `510`, it's `$array_item[0][0]`. If I want `984`, it's `$array_item[0][1]`. If I want `1163`, it's `$array_item[1][0]`. If I want `september`, it's `$array_item[2][3]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `$inner[0]` is one of the inner array elements, like `510`. You can't loop over that.

If you just want to loop over `$array_item[0]`, don't loop over the whole array.

```
if (is_array($array_item[0])) {
    foreach ($array_item[0] as $value) {
        echo "$value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't have the values I want returned to me, I only want what is specifically under [0] and not the entire thing.

Comment: Then why did you do `foreach ($array_item as $inner)`? I've updated the answer.

Comment: I got stuck on the idea because of how I assembled the array I think... since I was storying arrays inside the array... like: $array_item = array( $another_array) and so on...   Thanks for clearing it up, seems so stupid simple now.

Comment: You don't have to do this foreach either, just use implode as shown below. echo implode(PHP_EOL, $array_item[0]); would work

Answer (score 0):

Does is_array($array_item) return true?

```
if (is_array($array_item)) {
    foreach ($array_item) {
        if (is_array($inner)) {
            foreach ($inner as $value) {
                echo "$value \n";
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Edit: Also, $inner[0] is not an array.  $inner is the array.

Comment: is_array($array_item) is returning true, yes.

Comment: Ah, do not use $inner[0].  Inner[0] is a value, not an array.  Use foreach($inner as $value) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use implode, http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
foreach($array_items as $items) {
    echo implode(', ', $items);
}
```

I see that a comment was made that he wants only the first array to be outputted and not all of them.

```
if (is_array($array_item[0])) {
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $array_item[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never can tell what could solve a problem

```
$array_group = array();

if (isset($array_item[0]) and is_array($array_item[0])) {
foreach ($array_item[0] as $value) {
    $array_group[] = $value;
}
```

`$array_group` should output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 510
    [1] => 984
    [2] => 1045
    [3] => 2068
    [4] => 1054
    [5] => 673
)
```